# SUM function needs automatically to adjust for changes to SQL DB entries

Tags: function, sum, libreoffice-calc

I'm using multiple Calc tables in a single document for ingoing and outgoing bills that are stored in a SQL DB. Table A has ingoing bills and Table B has outgoing bills. For example table A has data from B2-B39 and table B has data from B2-B15. I need the sum function to automatically adjust when data entries are added or subtracted.

I can use `=SUM(B2:B39)` in tableA.B40 and `=SUM(B2:B15)` in tableB.B16 to get the sums of the current data, at the end of the data entries. However, when the DB changes, for example Table A has data from B2-B44, I end up missing five entries. To further complicate things, I have Table C, where I evaluate the net income. For example in Table C I use tableB.B16-tableA.B40. When the number of entries in tables A and B change the function in Table C no longer works.

I need SUM in multiple tables to automatically adjust its position based on how many rows of data are found in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something about your layout that you have not mentioned but a solution would *seem* to be to apply whole column references (eg `=SUM(B:B)`), or if you must have the total in the same column move it to the top and sum like so:

```
=SUM(B2:B1048576)
```

Otherwise try something like LibreOffice Basic and search for the first empty cell in the column to put the formula in.